# Dynamic Sheet loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

What I Have:

In a workbook, I have Setup Sheet, Summary Sheet and 2013 sheet To 2018 Sheets(Goes along with years)

What I Want:

I Have to go Each Sheet in a workbook(Starts From 2013 to End of the Year Sheet Suppose I Have 2018) goto Each Sheet data some do operations then that data will be displayed on to the Summary Sheet. How do I go to each sheet starts from 2013 to 2018(goes along with years)?

Tq In Advance

Comment: Hi! Can you show us what you've tried so far? Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and spend some time with the tutorial in the start to understand how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

you could do as follows:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In Worksheets ' loop through worksheets
    Select Case sht.Name ' check current sht name
        Case "Summary", "Setup" ' if a "forbidden" one
            ' do nothing
        Case Else ' otherwise
            ' here put your code to process current sht object
    End Select
Next
```